# XSL FO Repeat contents of split spanned cell

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using apache FOP 0.95 (and docbook on top of it) and I would like to repeat the content of a table cell spanning multiple rows whenever a page break happens.  At the moment the cell content is only displayed on the first page while an empty cell is displayed in all other pages.

I know this is part of the XSL FO 2.0 requirements, I believe not yet final.

I am a beginner with xsl transformations and I was wondering if there is a way to define a template to achieve this.

Thanks,
Pierpaolo

Comment: Are you referring to http://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20/#d2e18534?

Comment: Yep that is the one.  In here there is also a picture visualizing the concept: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20-req/#N66269

Comment: You can do it with AH Formatter using `axf:repeat-cell-content-at-break`.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-ext.html#table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am a beginner with xsl transformations and I was wondering if there is a way to define a template to achieve this.

The answer is almost certainly no. You are referring to a suggested new feature that might be included in a future XSL (XSL-FO) specification. Conformant XSL-FO processors will implement the feature if it is considered valuable enough.

XSLT and XSL-FO are related in the sense that the former is the most common way to generate the latter. But in general, you can't enhance the functionality of an XSL-FO processor by writing a clever XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback; I kind of thought that might be the case.